# Can't get HTML text to stay centered inside of div on responsive layout

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

Got an issue where I'm trying to have text stay centered in the middle of a div that's on top of an image. Looks good on desktop but once I start to attempt to make it mobile, it gets screwed up. I think it's because I'm using fixed heights in the div but I tried height:auto; and all that did was place the text to align to the top because it has no idea what the div height really is. Anyone know a better solution to this?

First here, here's the site in question: http://originalchuck.com/
It's in the middle of the page. The three large images.

Now, here's the CSS I'm currently using:

```
span.text-content, div.homepage-bags span.text-content-bags { color: #fff; display: table; font-size: 30px; left: 0px; position: absolute; top: 0px; text-shadow: 2px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 0px 1px 3px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5); text-transform: uppercase; width: 100%; }

div.homepage-featured span.text-content { height: 620px!important; }

div.homepage-buckets span.text-content { height: 288px!important; }

div.homepage-bags span.text-content-bags { height: 288px!important; }

div.homepage-featured span.text-content span, div.homepage-bags span.text-content-bags span { display: table-cell; text-align: center; vertical-align: middle; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use height !important for each `span.text-content`. It should work fine just with `height: 100%;` here.
Also remove `display: table;` from `span.text-content`, we'll center inner span absolutely.
For inner span:

```
span.text-content span {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -12px;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Text in the hover layer is short, so we can expect that it will never wrap. This means that useing top:50% with matgin-top minus half of text height is ok for vertical centering.

Also you'd better set `display: inline-block` for tag `a` here as there is an issue with overlay width on the first image on mobile.

Comment: Seems to work. Only issue is once I hit phone display, the text doesn't appear centered on the first of the three images, which is now on top. I think that's because the text is above the div and not necessarily the image, which is smaller. So I just have to resize the image width I guess.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries, i've come to a possible solution for you. Use this CSS on your `span.text-content` :

```
display: block;
height: 0 !important;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
left: 0;
right: 0;
margin: auto;
line-height: 0;
text-align: center;
```

And unwrap your text out of its `span` so you just have your naked text inside your `span.text-content`

Basically, the `margin: auto` causes the browser to resolve the conflicting height properties (100% given by `top: 0;` and `bottom: 0;` and the `height: 0;` and use the specified height (here, 0) and center it inside the container from the specified positions.

PS: The `!important` was solely here to override the heights you had hard-coded.